# FabricMC - Ghosting occuring when trying to render text to screen

Tags: java, minecraft-fabric

pretty new to fabric, im having some trouble with ghost lettering when I am rendering text the the screen.

It works with the default text renderer fine. However I would like to use a custom font, it renders but seems to ghost the lettering

Here is where I am: (Sorry for the lack of comments)

```
package turdz.daycounter.client;

import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.JsonArray;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.mojang.blaze3d.systems.RenderSystem;
import net.fabricmc.fabric.api.client.rendering.v1.HudRenderCallback;
import net.minecraft.client.MinecraftClient;
import net.minecraft.client.font.Font;
import net.minecraft.client.font.FontStorage;
import net.minecraft.client.font.FontType;
import net.minecraft.client.font.TextRenderer;
import net.minecraft.client.gui.DrawableHelper;
import net.minecraft.client.util.math.MatrixStack;
import net.minecraft.text.Text;
import net.minecraft.util.Identifier;


import net.minecraft.util.JsonHelper;
import turdz.daycounter.DayCounter;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class DayOverlay implements HudRenderCallback {

private static final Identifier DIED = new Identifier(DayCounter.MOD_ID, "textures/aliveicon/dead.png");
private static final Identifier ALIVE = new Identifier(DayCounter.MOD_ID, "textures/aliveicon/alive.png");
private static final MinecraftClient CLIENT = MinecraftClient.getInstance();


@Override
public void onHudRender(MatrixStack matrixStack, float tickDelta) {

    RenderSystem.setShaderColor(1.0 f, 1.0 f, 1.0 f, 1.0 f);

    matrixStack.push();
    matrixStack.scale(5.0 f, 5.0 f, 5.0 f);

    assert CLIENT.player != null;
    TextRenderer textRenderer = generateTextRenderer();

    textRenderer.draw(matrixStack, Text.literal("§l" + CLIENT.player.getName().getString()).asOrderedText(), 32, 12, 0xffffff);

    if (CLIENT.player.isDead()) {

        textRenderer.draw(matrixStack, Text.literal("§lDay: "), 32, 22, 0xff0000);
        textRenderer.draw(matrixStack, Text.literal("§l" + CLIENT.player.getWorld().getTimeOfDay() / 24000), 58, 22, 0x770000);

        RenderSystem.setShaderTexture(0, DIED);
        DrawableHelper.drawTexture(matrixStack, 10, 10, 0, 0, 20, 20, 20, 20);

    } else {

        textRenderer.draw(matrixStack, Text.literal("§lDay: "), 32, 22, 0xffffff);
        textRenderer.draw(matrixStack, Text.literal("§l" + CLIENT.player.getWorld().getTimeOfDay() / 24000), 58, 22, 0xffff00);

        RenderSystem.setShaderTexture(0, ALIVE);
        DrawableHelper.drawTexture(matrixStack, 10, 10, 0, 0, 20, 20, 20, 20);

    }

    matrixStack.pop();
}
private static TextRenderer generateTextRenderer() {

    List < Font > list = new ArrayList < > ();
    String json = "{\"providers\":[{\"type\":\"ttf\",\"file\":\"daycounter:arial.ttf\",\"shift\":[0,0],\"oversample\":5}]}";
    JsonArray jsonArray = JsonHelper.getArray(JsonHelper.deserialize(new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().disableHtmlEscaping().create(), json, JsonObject.class), "providers");

    for (int i = jsonArray.size() - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        JsonObject jsonObject = JsonHelper.asObject(jsonArray.get(i), "providers[" + i + "]");
        try {
            String stringType = JsonHelper.getString(jsonObject, "type");
            FontType fontType = FontType.byId(stringType);
            Font font = fontType.createLoader(jsonObject).load(CLIENT.getResourceManager());
            if (font != null)
                list.add(font);
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    FontStorage storage = new FontStorage(CLIENT.getTextureManager(), new Identifier("storageidentifier"));
    storage.setFonts(list);
    return new TextRenderer(identifier - > storage, true);
}
```

}

Here is an image of what going on. I scaled it up so it can be seen easier.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what was wrong. I was using the character to bold the default text on a custom font. removed the character and all is good.

The character in question is "§l". Hope this helps someone at some point.

Revised Code:

```
@Override
public void onHudRender(MatrixStack matrixStack, float tickDelta) {


    RenderSystem.setShaderColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

    matrixStack.push();
    matrixStack.scale(5.0f, 5.0f, 5.0f);

    assert CLIENT.player != null;
    TextRenderer textRenderer = generateTextRenderer();
    
    //Revised this line to remove special character.
    textRenderer.draw(matrixStack, Text.literal(CLIENT.player.getName().getString()).asOrderedText(), 32,12,0xffffff);
    if(CLIENT.player.isDead()){
        
        //Revised this line to remove special character.
        textRenderer.draw(matrixStack, Text.literal("Day: "), 32,22,0xff0000);
        //Revised this line to remove special character.
        textRenderer.draw(matrixStack, Text.literal("" + CLIENT.player.getWorld().getTimeOfDay() / 24000), 58,22,0x770000);

        RenderSystem.setShaderTexture(0, DIED);
        DrawableHelper.drawTexture(matrixStack, 10, 10, 0, 0, 20, 20, 20 ,20);

    } else {

        //Revised this line to remove special character.
        textRenderer.draw(matrixStack, Text.literal("Day: "), 32,22,0xffffff);
        //Revised this line to remove special character.
        textRenderer.draw(matrixStack, Text.literal("" + CLIENT.player.getWorld().getTimeOfDay() / 24000), 58,22,0xffff00);

        RenderSystem.setShaderTexture(0, ALIVE);
        DrawableHelper.drawTexture(matrixStack, 10, 10, 0, 0, 20, 20, 20 ,20);

    }

    matrixStack.pop();
}
```